# How to access the EntityManager from a functional test class in Symfony 5?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, phpunit, functional-testing, symfony5

I'm working on a Symfony 5 app. In a functional test (`WebTestCase`) I want to check the database result of a request. For that I need access to the / an `EntityManger`. So I tried that like this (as recommended in the ["Functional Testing of A Doctrine Repository"](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html#functional-testing-of-a-doctrine-repository) section of the Symfony Testing tutorial):

**`AbstractWebTestCase`**

```
abstract class AbstractWebTestCase extends WebTestCase
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->entityManager;
    }

    // a convenience method for creating an authenticated user
    protected function createAuthenticatedUser($username, $password)
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->request('POST', '/api/login', [], [], ['CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'],
            json_encode(['username' => $username,'password' => $password,]));
        $data = json_decode($client->getResponse()->getContent(), true);
        $client->setServerParameter('HTTP_Authorization', sprintf('Bearer %s', $data['token']));
        return $client;
    }

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();
        $this->entityManager = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    }

    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        $this->entityManager->close();
        $this->entityManager = null;
    }
}
```

**`FooControllerTest`**

```
class FooControllerTest extends AbstractWebTestCase
{
    public function testFoo(): void
    {
        $client = $this->createAuthenticatedUser('foo@foo.com', 'pwd');
        $client->request('POST', '/api/uri/foo', [], [], ['CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'], '{...}'
        );
        ...
        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
    }
}
```

But now my tests are running into an error:

> App\Tests\Controller\MyConcreteControllerTest::testDoSomething
> LogicException: Booting the kernel before calling "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase::createClient()" is not supported, the kernel should only be booted once.

How to resolve this and get access to the / an `EntityManager` in a functional test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The / A solution is to call the `static::createClient()` only in the `setUp()`:

**`AbstractWebTestCase`**

```
abstract class AbstractWebTestCase extends WebTestCase
{
    private $entityManager;
    private $client;

    public function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->entityManager;
    }

    // a convenience method for creating an authenticated user
    protected function createAuthenticatedUser($username, $password)
    {
        $this->client->request('POST', '/api/login', [], [], ['CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'],
            json_encode(['username' => $username,'password' => $password,]));
        $data = json_decode($this->client->getResponse()->getContent(), true);
        $this->client->setServerParameter('HTTP_Authorization', sprintf('Bearer %s', $data['token']));
        return $this->client;
    }

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->client = static::createClient();
        $this->entityManager = static::$container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    }

    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        $this->entityManager->close();
        $this->entityManager = null;
    }
}
```

Are there better / more elegant solutions?

Comment: Others might be able to better comment if you could also outline your earlier understanding with the kernel in your question and how the create-client variant in your answer makes the difference for you.